Infinite Ramsey Theorem analogue for infinite complete Bipartite Graphs
The version of the Infinite Ramsey Theorem I am interested in states that for any countably infinite complete graph $K_{\aleph_0}$ edge-coloured by $f: E(K_{\aleph_0}) \to [1, c]$ (with $c \in \mathbb{N}$) there is an induced monochromatic subgraph $K_{\aleph_0}$.
Does this transfer to countably infinite complete bipartite graphs? More specifically, taking any $K_{\aleph_0, \aleph_0}$ and edge-colouring $f: E(K_{\aleph_0,\aleph_0}) \to [1, c]$ is there an induced monochromatic subgraph $K_{\aleph_0, \aleph_0}$?
The answer to a finite variant of this problem (Ramsey's theorem of complete bipartite graph) seems to imply that there is an induced monochromatic $K_{n, \aleph_0}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but I do not see how this can be extended to the required case above.

In a sense, the post you mentioned holds a clue for the answer. Define $c:\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\to \{1,2\}$ by letting $c(i,j)=1$ if $i<j$ and $c(i,j)=2$ if $i\geq j$. There are two ways to see that there is no monochromatic $K_{\aleph_0,\aleph_0}$ subgraph.

Observe that each left vertex has finite $2$-degree and each right vertex has finite $1$-degree. Thus, if $H$ is a monochromatic subgraph of either color, then one side of $H$ must be finite.

Suppose $L\subseteq\mathbb N$ and $R\subseteq \mathbb N$ are infinite. This means for any $i\in L$ there exists some $j\in R$ with $j>i$, and for any $j\in R$ there exists some $i\in L$ with $i\geq j$. So $L\times R$ cannot be monochromatic with respect to $c$.


